# Set with uncountable many cut-points and uncountable many non-cut points

Tags: general-topology

I was wondering if there is a set (in any topological space) with uncountable many cut-points and uncountable many non-cut points. If yes, an example would be great! (better in  $\mathbb{R}^n$ but not necessary).

Thank you all in advance

Alberto

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take the closed unit ball in $\mathbb R^n$, $n\ge 2$, together with one of the axes.